# In postback, alter the contents of field that is shown by Masterpage code-behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am writing an asp.net application. In my project some output to page is caused by MasterPage.master.cs code-behind.  
Namely, some page header is rendered and few text fields are indicated about current status.
Now I have a situation, when after a postback one of such text fields are altered. Tracing shows that Masterpage code (attached to its Page_Load method)  runs before postback handler.
 So the field is altered in program but its indication in the header is not altered before I reload the page again - simply because indication happens before handler is invoked.
I need a good way to alter that header after postback. Perhaps some javascript call on onLoad. or some C# trick. I appreciate all the input.
My code is :

```
masterpage.master.cs: 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { PROJECTS project = 
Util.getProject(Session); ProjectName.Text = "Project: " + (String)project.NAME;
ProjectName.Visible = true; }
```

Comment: Please paste your code. and what you have tried..????

Comment: In masterpage.master.cs:   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   PROJECTS project = Util.getProject(Session);
 
            ProjectName.Text = "Project: " + (String)project.NAME;
            ProjectName.Visible = true;
  }

Comment: What causes the postback? an asp:button? pls paste the page_load and html code! and pls edit your post and paste the code properly formated!

Comment: and then on postback project is altered and stored to Session (which is progam's Httpsession storage)

Comment: postback is caused by change of drop-down list of projects (asp-based dropdown list)